# HTML Link on image stops working when CSS is added, how can I fix this?

Tags: html, css

Without the CSS, when I click the link, it takes me to the YouTube page (like it should).
However, when I add the CSS, it doesnt.

How could I fix this so that I can have the link work with the CSS?
(**Note:** I am using Google Chrome)

```css
.button {
    display:block;
    width:250px;
    height:175px;
    position:fixed;
    top:53%;
    left:32.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
    <a href="http://fpoimg.com/">
        <img src="http://fpoimg.com/300x250" alt="YouTube">
    </a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** I do not believe that it is even registering that my mouse is over the image, because hover and active CSS tags do not work. Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: That markup alone works just fine. There is something else that must besides what you have given us that must be causing the behavior. Are you sure you do not have any JS binding to that class?

Comment: Hi guys; I replaced the original code with a snippet that was pointing to youtube. Youtube blocked being loaded into an iframe.

Comment: I agree with Travis, there must be something else on the page blocking it.

Comment: If you create your own page, the markup worked with YouTube. In any case, it all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the height of an element above it was covering the image, so the height of that element was blocking the image from being clicked or activating the hover selector for the image.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube refused to redirect your current tab to `youtube.com` due to this error:

`Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

To avoid this simply add `target="_blank"` to your `<a>` tag.

`<a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">`

which `target="_blank"` opens a new tab for you with the url `https://www.youtube.com` in it instead of replacing your current tab.

hope that helps
[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/9hqbnf0t/)

Comment: I edited the original to use code snippet which doesn work with youtube; I then changed and now it works. I dont think the sameorigin issue is what the original poster was running into.

Comment: The original markup works if you create your own page but not with SO's built in thing.

Comment: I believe there is something else going on in your end we do not know, because by default it should work, perhaps investigate web console and feed us with more details.

Comment: I do not see anything in the console when I click on the image. Hover and active CSS tags do not work for the image either. Could this be the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is violating the mixed content security policy.

As per the error messages in console...

**Chrome:** `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990704/html-link-on-image-stops-working-when-css-is-added-how-can-i-fix-this' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://fpoimg.com/300x250'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.`

**Firefox:** `Blocked loading mixed active content "http://fpoimg.com/"`

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default)

> Mixed passive/display content is content served over HTTP that is included in an HTTPS webpage, but that cannot alter other portions of the webpage. For example, an attacker could replace an image served over HTTP with an inappropriate image or message to the user. The attacker could also infer information about the user's activities by watching which images are served to the user; often images are only served on a specific page within a website. If the attacker observes HTTP requests to certain images, they could determine which webpage the user is visiting.

---

As you can see, the css actually plays no role in blocking this functionality.

```html
<div class="button">
    <a href="http://fpoimg.com/">
        <img src="http://fpoimg.com/300x250">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use  tag. Just surround your  with  tag, and design your link like your button if needed :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I added this around my image:     <p id="YouTubeImage"><img src="YouTube.png" alt="YouTube"></p>, but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: Working with "_blank" tag. <a href="http://fpoimg.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://fpoimg.com/300x250" alt="YouTube"></a>